# How to show only Product Name and price in specific category magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, catalog, custom-block

I am working on specific category so I need to show some customized changes in that for that I need to show only product Name and price and by clicking on that I have continued button I am confused how can I remove other details

I tried to like this in my `catalog_category_view.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <block class="test\QuickShop\Block\CustomOptions" name="custom.category.form"
                   template="test_QuickShop::quickshop/quickshop.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

but it's not working.
Anything I am missing here?

Comment: you need to remove the only cart button?

Comment: Please update your question some more information

Comment: Please add your block file and phtml file code for more information about it.